# Display one post at a time in a single page application using PHP, JQuery, for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I want to display one post at a time inside a div and replace the content to display the next (adjacent) post's content on the click of a button.

I am currently looping through the posts using `wp_query`, but all posts are displayed stacked on top of each other.

```
query_posts($args);
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$count = $wp_query->post_count;
$i = 1;
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() && $i < 9) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
```

I am pulling in the following content:
`<?php echo $i?> / <?php echo $count?>`
`<?php the_title();?>`
`<?php the_content();?>`

I also have a conditional surrounding the button to pull in the adjacent link's permalink, but it is grabbing the entirety of the permalink when I only need the post's slug. I'm imagining something like this, but it doesn't work:
`$next_slug = get_slug(get_adjacent_post(false, '', false));`

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially AJAX navigation through posts. [This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/274414) should be able to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <?php the_title( '<h1>','</h1>' );  ?>
        <div class="post-thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(250, 250)); ?> </div>
        <div class="entry-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        <div class="btn"><?php next_post_link('%link', '%title'); ?></div>
    </article>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
```